Using JSON dictonary keys as column entries in AWS Glue
I have JSON files with the following structure:
{
 'ID_001': 
  {
   'attr_a': 'bla',
   'attr_b': 'blub'
  },
 'ID_002':
  {
   'attr_a': 'foo',
   'attr_b': 'bar'
  },
 ...
}

I'd like to translate this into a table format with an AWS Glue ETL task that has the following format:



ID
attr_a
attr_b




ID_001
bla
blub


ID_002
foo
bar


...





However, I'm getting stuck with tables that are like



ID_001
ID_002
...



In pandas a simple df.transpose() does the trick, but with the DynamicFrameCollection that I get in a custom transform I am getting stuck.
Is there a preferred way to do such a transformation in Spark/AWS Glue? Or is there a better way to read that data into an Athena table?

maybe easier to read json string and prepare it in advance like so:
data = [(k, v['attr_a'], v['attr_b']) for k, v in json_string.items()]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'attr_a', 'attr_b'])
display(df)

output :



id
attr_a
attr_b




ID_001
bla
blub


ID_002
foo
bar




You can use relationalize to flatten the json.
Documentation
from awsglue.transforms import SelectFromCollection
relationalize_1 = Relationalize.apply(<dynamicframe_name>)

you will get a collection of DynamicFrames after you transform using Relationalize,  you will need to select the appropriate one, as an example since your json starts with ID_001, I used ID_001
selected_frame = SelectFromCollection.apply(relationalize_1, "ID_001")

selected_frame should contain your flattened structure.

Just create a Map and then explode it:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = df.columns
df_new = df.select(F.explode(F.map_from_arrays(F.lit(cols), F.array(cols)))) \
           .selectExpr("key as ID", "value.*")
df_new.show()




ID
attr_a
attr_b




ID_001
bla
blub


ID_002
foo
bar



Or use an array of structs and then explode:
df_new = df.select(F.explode(F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(c).alias('ID'), F.col(c).alias('value')) for c in cols])).alias("item")) \
           .selectExpr("item.ID", "item.value.*")

